# Cutting a string based on the start keyword and end key word of the string python

Tags: python, apache-tika

I have a pdf which I have read via Tika package in python. It seems tika can only read a whole pdf and i need to read only the first page.

My code looks like:

```
from tika import parser
raw = parser.from_file(pdfname)
rawtext = raw['content']
```

I would like to split the rawtext by start keyword and end keyword. How do I do that?

Comment: Probably the iteration and breaking after the first cycle can help you. Refer: https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python/issues/191#issuecomment-552593722

Comment: @rkatkam, thank you very much. that was helpful.

Comment: how do u change that code to just read one page?

Comment: When you pass the `xmlContent` flag to be True in `parser`, the pdf contents are wrapped into `div` elements corresponding to every page. And instead of the for loop, you can use the first element of `xhtml_data.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'page'})` output

Comment: how do i use the first element?

Comment: By indexing. `xhtml_data.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'page'})[0]`

Comment: @rkatkam, doesn't work. xhtml_data.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'page'})[0], doesnt work.

Comment: You might want to check in BeautifulSoup doc to find first occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `regex` to select the text that you are interested, for example:

```py
import re


raw_text = 'this is a sample of text'
start = 'is'
end = 'of'

start_index = re.search(r'\b' + start + r'\b', raw_text).start()
end_index = re.search(r'\b' + end + r'\b', raw_text).end()
section_of_text = raw_text[start_index:end_index]
print(section_of_text)

>>> "is a sample of"
```